# Native audio recording in Android using OpenSL ES

Tags: android, android-ndk, opensl

I'm trying to use OpenSL ES for Android in my project in order to provide a low-latency and I found that NDK sample NativeAudio is designed only for recording a short snapshots.

Could you please advise me, where can I find a samples of how to record audio with a long duration?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever been able to get this working with a USB audio input? Running it on the Nexus 9 and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the [blog by Victor Lazzarini](http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/android-audio-streaming-with-opensl-es-and-the-ndk/) which provides excellent example for recording with OpenSL ES. Atleast this can be your start point.

Comment: Private access only

Answer (score 2):

the native-audio sample is updated to playback in low latency path; a new sample [audio-echo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/audio-echo) is created to loop back audio in low latency path on Android.